# Oops. The email address is badly formatted Firebase / Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the error "Oops. The email address is badly formatted." also when I don't even fill anything in.

I've already tried importing Firebase on a different spot, but it didn't fix the issue.

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  name: "login",
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    login: function() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(
          function(user = user) {
            alert("Well done! You are now logged in");
          },
          function(err) {
            alert("Oops. " + err.message);
          }
        );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you're getting an error message from the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, then the call in itself works fine. It's more likely that the values you're passing in are incorrect, such as having a quote in the email address as SalunkeAkash answered. If you can't find the problem, you might want to `console.log(this.email, this.password)` right before you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, and see what that logs.

Answer (score 1):

hey you can if the email id is with qoutes or not

you can check that in inspect network

Comment: This is not the case

Comment: As @frank-van-puffelen said, are you getting proper values for `console.log(this.email, this.password)` right before you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` ?

Comment: undefined, 3 times

Comment: that is the error that's why you are getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following code:

```
    <script>
  import firebase from 'firebase';
  export default {
    name: 'login',
    data() {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login: function() {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
          (user) => {
            this.$router.replace('home')
          },
          (err) => {
            alert('Oops. ' + err.message)
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```